# How do I use DateTimeIndex as input for named function in apply() across Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DateTimeIndex consisting of 15-minute intervals.

I also have the same function written in 2 ways that I want to apply across the whole Data Frame. The point of the function is to get if a particular day is a weekday or not.

Here they are:

```
def weekend(datum):
    if (datum.weekday() == 5) or (datum.weekday() == 6):
        return "Weekend"
    else:
        return "Working day"
 # written with being fed the DateTimeIndex in mind


def weekendfromnumber(number):
    if (number == 5) or (number == 6):
        return "Weekend"
    else:
        return "Working day"
# written with being fed the integer of the intermediate columng weekday in mind
```

I wanted to apply the first function by feeding it with DateTimeIndex directly as in :

```
df15['Type of day'] = df15.index.apply(weekend)
```

but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

If I use the second function as in:

```
df15['Type of day'] = df15.weekday.apply(weekendfromnumber)
```

I get the effect that I want but at the cost of needing to create an intermediate column named weekday with:

```
df15['weekday'] = df15.index.weekday
```

Since I do not want an intermediate column I thought that doing something like:

```
df15['Type of day'] = df15.index.weekday.apply(weekendfromnumber)
```

would work, but instead I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

So, the overarching question is:

**How do I use the data that is already in the DateTimeIndex and feed it to a custom function using apply()?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create a temporary `pd.Series` for your datetime index, but why not just use `np.where` as it is much faster here:

```
df15['Type of day'] = np.where(df15.index.weekday > 5, "Weekend", "Working Day")
```

If your function is complicated and you cannot use np.where, call `to_series()` first:

```
df15['Type of day'] = df15.index.to_series().apply(weekend)
```

**Timings:**

Tested with a dummy dataframe with 100 rows and one column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,1), 
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='D', 
                                         start='2017-01-01',
                                         periods=100))

In [1]: %timeit df.index.to_series().apply(weekend)
1.11 ms ± 127 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit np.where(df.index.weekday > 5, "Weekend", "Weekday")
192 µs ± 45.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks that works like a charm in this particular case.

However the problem remains if I have a more complicated function (the one in example was for the sake of simplicity) that still needs to be fed the complete information from the index.

For example I would like to get a value from the "future" rows that satisify a condition based on features of current row's DateTimeIndex value as in "Next Thursday", "next 24 hours", "next month", "next working day". All of the rows that satisfy those criteria vary whether the input is 23:45 on Sunday the 28th or it is 10:15 on Monday the 2nd.

Comment: I added the to_series() option and timings too. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if that solved your problem, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. That is it. I can feed it now to every function. 

Still the logic behind me escapes me: Why can I apply apply() to any other column except DateTimeIndex?

Comment: I don't have an answer as to why you can't, sorry.